# Prevent showing debugging log info inside ipython shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, ipython

I'm using scrapy shell inside virtualenv. IPython is installed inside virtualenv. When I start scrapy shell using

```
 scrapy shell 'https://example.com'
```

and press tab for autocomplete suggestions, it shows a lot of debug information. How can I disable this?

```
In [1]: from scra2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser start
2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser calculated
2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff: line_lengths old: 1, new: 1
2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff replace old[1:1] new[1:1]
2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: parse_part from 1 to 1 (to 0 in part parser)
2018-03-23 10:05:45 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser end
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10946 looks like it's reported bug here.

In case you need debug logging in ipython, try to

```
logging.getLogger('parso.cache').disabled=True
logging.getLogger('parso.cache.pickle').disabled=True
```

and keep wait for parso update
UPD: fixed in iPython 8.15+

Comment: Yes, this issue was exactly same as mine.

Comment: Is there a way to auto run this when you start the shell ?

Comment: Just add this to ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py

Comment: Working solution here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10946#issuecomment-354501461

Comment: For me what worked was doing `logging.getLogger('parso').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

Answer (score 11):

Try doing this to set the logging level to `WARNING`:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING);
```

Any log messages of level `INFO` or `DEBUG` shouldn't appear anymore. You can also set the log level to `logging.ERROR`. Then `WARNING` messages won't appear as well.

Good luck!

Comment: It solved my problem. Instead of doing this every time, I have written this into my `settings.py`

Comment: Cool, glad that I could help! Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-L` command-line option to change the log level to `INFO`:

```
scrapy shell -L INFO https://example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set log level in settings.py file [as described in docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging-settings)

`LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'`

This will hide `DEBUG` level messages from scrapy.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer add this to your pythonstartup $PYTHONSTARTUP

```
try:
    _ = __IPYTHON__ 
    import IPython
    ip=IPython.get_ipython()
    c = ip.__dict__['Completer'] 
    import logging
    logging.getLogger('parso.cache').disabled=True
    logging.getLogger('parso.cache.pickle').disabled=True
    print(">> debug msg from $HOME/.pythonrc.py <<")
except NameError:
    pass # no ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute this code in shell:

```py
__import__("logging").getLogger("parso.python.diff").setLevel("INFO")
__import__("logging").getLogger("parso.cache").setLevel("INFO")
__import__("logging").getLogger("asyncio").setLevel("INFO")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm bearing it for a long time, not found an ideal solution, after I uninstalled parso module, all is well!

```
pip uninstall parso
```